# Can I reuse the offer of WebRTC once connection got disconnected?

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc, p2p

I am trying to create a P2P network between two devices. I want them to be connected to each other all the time and if they got disconnected they can reconnect again. I am trying this in WebRTC without a signaling server, but after it got disconnect for the first time I have to again create new offer and accept_offer "SDP" and connect them manually.
My question is:

1. Is their a way to setup this once ? To made them connect for once and reuse the "SDP" token indefinitely  for reconnection?
2. Or another way to achieve this kind of setup?

*NOTE: The 2 devices are not on the same network they are over the internet and want to reuse the offer for single client only*

I have tried to make a bunch of tokens at once and tried to use them one by one but only the most recently generated token is valid for establishing connection

Comment: This is my main resource and code: https://mac-blog.org.ua/webrtc-one-to-one-without-signaling-server/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

##### Is their a way to setup this once ... and reuse the "SDP" token indefinitely?

In theory it may be possible over a LAN perhaps where network conditions never change. But over the internet and indefinitely? No.

SDP describes media, codecs, formats, underlying transport, session keys, and network settings.

While SDP can be hard-coded to some extent for initial offers and answers, once ICE gathering starts, the SDP grows to include ICE candidates (network address pairs) specific to your current network situation — make sure you wait for that to show up in the SDP if you don't have signaling — But with routers and ISPs that stuff rarely stays still, and hard-coding that is going to be brittle.

But I grew interested in your initial question:

##### Can I reuse the offer of WebRTC once connection got disconnected?

I wondered: would it work at all in current browsers even over a smaller temporary network drop?

So I tested it. Turns out not reliably, but it seems to work somewhat in Chrome, though not in Safari or Firefox. I see Chrome reconnect after a disconnect in the following proof of concept:

```js
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = async () => {
  while (pc.iceConnectionState == "disconnected") {
    console.log("Attempt to reconnect in 10 seconds...");
    await wait(10000);
    console.log("Attempting reconnect...");
    if (pc.remoteDescription.type == "answer") {
      await pc.setLocalDescription();
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(pc.remoteDescription);
    } else {
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(pc.remoteDescription);
      await pc.setLocalDescription();
    }
  }
};
```

To test it, follow these steps:

1. Open https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/jyvu6k7q/show in Chrome on two different machines (or two windows) A and B on the same wifi (macs are great as they offer cut'n'paste over icloud).
2. On machine A, press the <kbd>Offer</kbd> button and copy the offer to the
   clipboard.
3. On machine B, paste that offer into "Paste offer here" and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
4. Copy the answer that appears after a few seconds.
5. Return to machine A and paste that answer where it says "Paste answer here" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a message saying you're "connected". Type in the chat box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm!

6. On A click <kbd>AddTrack</kbd> to send video to B.
7. On B click <kbd>AddTrack</kbd> to send video to A.

You should now have live video sending both ways.

8. Now to simulate a network drop, turn off Wifi on BOTH machines at the same time (helps with timing).

The incoming video should freeze on both A and B.

9. After 5 seconds turn Wifi back on on BOTH machines.

In Chrome incoming video should resume on both A and B after a few seconds and "disconnected" should switch back to "connected".

Limitations: This is really just renegotiation (not reusing offers/answers for new peer connections). It may take a couple of attempts to reconnect, and this may not be reliable. Data channels may time out and close etc. It also doesn't recover reliably work in other browsers. I wonder if that's a bug?

Comment: the ICE stacks in Chrome and Firefox behave differently. If the ICE connection state does not go to "failed" they should be able to reconnect without an ICE restart.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Hmm, yeah after further testing, my renegotiation rain dance here seems unnecessary, as Chrome reconnects and gets out of `disconnected` by itself. I should retest and let it go to `failed` first.